# How to create product price in real time based on forms?

Tags: catalog

I would create a product where price is made dynamically based on a form. You can see an example here (web site made with magento): http://minimegaprint.com/pieghevoli.html.

I have Made a form that with some calculus can calcolate a custom price.
Is there a way or extension or custom code that can send this custom price to magento product price?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

If you ask me, this can be mapped with configurable products or custom options.

But if you want your own price logic, you can do it this way:
Every time a product is added to the cart or you visit the cart page, a `collectTotals()` is called.

There is an event: `sales_quote_collect_totals_before`

After this event, there is a loop over all quote-items. For ever item, the product is fetched and the price of the quote-item is updated. So you can prefetch all the products and add whatever price you want:

```
public function salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote */
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            // I'm not yet sure, what price is needed hiere
            $price = $someHelper->getPriceWithoutTax($product); 
            $product->setPrice($price);
        }
    }
}
```

and the configuration in the `config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
                <observers>
                    <my_pricing>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore</method>
                    </my_pricing>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example working?
In your opinion this http://minimegaprint.com/pieghevoli.html. is done by core customization or with custom options/cpnfigurable product?

Comment: The code should work with a few modifications. If you want me to solve your problem, you find my email in my profile. To answer your second question: No idea, can be everything. This can be done with both options. If you want to track your qtys you need configurable products, but then you have lots and lots of simples. So if this doesn't matter custom options are easier to build.