# Overriding Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price Not Work for Configurable and Downloadable Product

Tags: model

I have successfully override Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price to edit the `getPrice` function with this code.

```
class Myc_Mymodule_Model_Product_Type_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
{

    public function getPrice($product)
    {
        return 10;
    }
```

This works for simple and grouped product, but it's not work for Configurable and Downloadable Product.

But if I edit `getPrice` function directly in the core file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php with the above code, it works for all product.

How this can happen? And how to make it works for all product by overiding `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that this model is only used for grouped and simple products. For configurables another model is used:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
```

And it extends from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` therefore your change works, if you edit the core file.

I answered here a question how to use an observer to change the price, maybe this helps you:
[How to create product price in real time based on forms?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/820/how-to-create-product-price-in-real-time-based-on-forms/821#821)

Comment: Thanks Fabian, you help me again. I think you know what I want based on my previous question you answered :D